# Jquery append to form lose decode entities

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to append some dynamically inputs to my form, the problem is that using jquery append method, it break html entities.

For example, try to write `I <3 JQUERY` inside textarea.
Textarea is initialized with CK EDITOR 5. I've tried also SUMMERNOTE with no success.

In my example the variable passed with POST `aa_a` is appended to post (IS WHAT I NEED). `aa` variable is original (It is passed as purpose only in this example).

`aa` is posted correctly

`aa_a` are decoded! (not wanted this!)

I'd like to `aa_a` (that is appended) is passed with same value as `aa`

[image]

**I NEED TO USE JQUERY APPEND TO ORIGINAL FORM FUNCTIONS** cause i've dynamic input in groups (input-1 with textarea-1, input-2 with textarea-2 etc...).

My example is stripped out to get you an example only.

Code example:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if ( isset($_POST) ) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="form" action="">
    <textarea name="aa" class="aa"><?php if isset($_POST) { echo $_POST['aa']; } ?></textarea>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="send">
</form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        editor.updateSourceElement();

        //alert($(".aa").val());
        //alert(editor.getData());

        var form = $("#form");
        form.append($('<textarea class="hidden" name="aa_a">'+ $(".aa").val() +'</textarea>') );
        form.submit();
    });

});

    ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '.aa' ), {
            // toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link' ]
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
    } );

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
form.append($('<textarea class="hidden" name="aa_a">'+ $(".aa").val().replace(/&/g, "&amp;") +'</textarea>') );
```

But in case I write in the form:

```
Commercial & is equal to &amp;
```

after POST I get inside form: `Commercial & is equal to &`